# After upgrading spring-boot from 2.3.5.RELEASE to 2.4.0, ProxyProvider is not found in the package reactor.netty.tcp

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, netty, reactor-netty

After upgrading from Spring Boot version 2.3.5.RELEASE to 2.4.0 in the pom.xml, the class ProxyProvider cannot be imported anymore (`import reactor.netty.tcp.ProxyProvider;`). Note that it does not work even with later versions of Spring Boot (tried the 2.5.0 and the 2.5.2).
By inspecting the Maven dependencies, I noticed that:

- In version 2.3.5.RELEASE, the class is taken from `io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty:0.9.12.RELEASE`
- In version 2.4.0, the class is taken from `io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-http:1.0.1`

I could find out this information on IntelliJ by inspecting the origin of the imported class `reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient`, which works on both versions, instead, despite from the two different libraries as described above.

Do you have any idea how to solve the compilation problem from Spring Boot 2.4.0 onwards?

Note that I found the same question in the issue tracker of Spring Boot, but unfortunately it was closed giving no explanation: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/24414 .

As further information, these are all the Netty dependencies in the case of 2.3.5.RELEASE:

[image: Spring Boot Version 2.3.5.RELEASE - Maven Dependencies analyzed with IntelliJ Maven Helper plugin]

And these when the Spring Boot release is 2.4.0:

[image: Spring Boot Version 2.4.0 - Maven Dependencies analyzed with IntelliJ Maven Helper plugin]

Also note that, in the pom.xml, I imported the dependency `azure-keyvault-secrets-spring-boot-starter` of version 2.3.5, in both cases (but it gives the same issue even with the latest version of that library, that has been moved to https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.azure.spring/azure-spring-boot-starter-keyvault-secrets/3.6.0) :

```xml
<!-- Azure KeyVault access (password safe) -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-keyvault-secrets-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>${azure.version}</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

This is the code that uses the ProxyProvider class:

```java
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create()
    .tcpConfiguration(tcpClient -> (sslContext != null
            ? tcpClient.secure(sslProviderBuilder -> sslProviderBuilder.sslContext(sslContext))
            : tcpClient)
            .proxy(proxy -> proxy
                    .type(ProxyProvider.Proxy.HTTP)
                    .host(host)
                    .port(port))
    );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution by noticing that, in my code, the method `tcpConfiguration` was deprecated on Spring Boot version 2.4.0. Then I tried to look for alternatives, and from this post in Github, I found a hint on how to improve the code: https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/1397#issuecomment-751976453. It said, in short, that

> Everything that you can configure via HttpClient.tcpConfiguration(), now you can configure using directly methods exposed by HttpClient

For anyone interested, I post here my updated code, that has the same logic of the code in the question, but without errors, in Spring Boot 2.4.0:

```java
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create();
            if (sslContext != null) {
                httpClient = httpClient.secure(sslContextSpec -> sslContextSpec.sslContext(sslContext));
            }
            httpClient = httpClient.proxy(typeSpec -> typeSpec.type(ProxyProvider.Proxy.HTTP).host(host).port(port));
```

In this case, the ProxyProvider class is still used, but it is from a different package: `reactor.netty.transport.ProxyProvider` (instead of `reactor.netty.tcp.ProxyProvider`).

Comment: In the Reactor Netty 1.0.0 release notes one can find all deprecated, moved or removed APIs. https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/releases/tag/v1.0.0

Comment: To help understand the new logic of the newer Reactor Netty versions, I found this guide useful: https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/reference/index.html#_proxy_support